# Android setBackgroundColor crashes application

Tags: android, android-layout, setbackground

This is a piece of code that is working for setbackground color tabwidget

`mTabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));`

However when I used different value of HEX: #FFC905, the application crashes.

What am I doing wrong? 
Android newbie here.

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code; and the logcat perhaps. My guess is that `getTabWidget()` is `null`, and trying to call `setBackgroundColor` on the `null` object is causing the crash. But it's impossible to diagnose without the logcat/relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of doing:

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Try to do :

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

But the logCat would really help

Comment: I don't know why it has stop 3 times before but its now working. Thank you for help